# Group columns but not protect them and password protect one of the group column

Tags: excel, vba

I Have 3 columns a,b,c which I want to group and show as grouped( collapsed section). Column B is locked and when I try to ungroup a,b,c columns it asks me password. I dont want it to ask the password as only column B is password protected not the grouping ungrouping action.

How can I solve this problem in excel/vba

Answer (score 0):

you can add a piece of code to run at beginning and end of your routine.  This will un-protect the sheet, run your code, then protect it again.

Begin:

```
Dim mypassword As String

mypassword = "yourPassword"

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:=mypassword
```

End:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:=mypassword
```